# The provided value 'undefined' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I am getting

```
The provided value 'undefined' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType. cfs_upload-http.js:109
```

when trying to upload a file using collectionfs. This does not affect the upload on the browser but seems to be keeping me from uploading in a mobile app. Any help on how to resolve this issue would be extremely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting same error using GridFS

Comment: I am getting the same thing as well from GridFS. It doesn't affect my project but i would like to know why it is causing a warning.